# Оптимизация кода Python ускорение

Tags: python, оптимизация

Код:

```
a = int(input())
b = int(input())
c = int(input())
d = 0
while a+b>c and b+c>a and a+c>b:
    d=d+1
    a=a-1
    b=b-1
    c=c-1
else:
    print(d)
```

Как оптимизировать код, чтобы он работал еще быстрее?

Comment: Что должен делать код?

Answer (score 3):

Как я понял, код считает минимальное кол-во шагов для приведения чисел в то состояние, когда сумма любых двух из них не превышает третье, отнимая за шаг по единице. В ускоренном алгоритме (см. примечание в коде `# алгоритм быстрее`) используется следующий подход.

Если числа сразу не подходят под условие, то:

1. Из всех чисел вычитается `минимум` из них же, так, что минимальное число превращается в ноль. Этот `минимум` и будет максимальным кол-вом шагов
2. Из оставшихся чисел: из максимального вычитается минимальное, эта разница и будет тем кол-вом шагов, которое нужно вычесть из максимального кол-ва шагов
3. Отнимаем, получаем минимальное кол-во шагов для приведения чисел в нужное состояние.

Код выводит сравнение результатов исходного кода и оптимизированного. Оптимизация заключается в отказе от цикла.

```
from random import randint

minr,maxr = 1000000,2000000
for i in range(10):
    i, j, k = randint(minr,maxr), randint(minr,maxr), randint(minr,maxr)
    a, b, c = i, j, k

    d = 0
    while a + b > c and b + c > a and a + c > b:
        d = d + 1
        a = a - 1
        b = b - 1
        c = c - 1
    else:
        res = d

    a, b, c = i, j, k
    # алгоритм быстрее
    d = 0
    if a + b > c and b + c > a and a + c > b:
        d = min(a, b, c)
        a, b, c = a - d, b - d, c - d
        lst = sorted((a, b, c))  # будет наподобие 0,35,42
        d -= lst[2] - lst[1]  # корректируем d на (максимум - минимум (кроме 0))
    res1 = d

    print(res, res1)
```

```
1445987 1445987
1752419 1752419
1220833 1220833
547070 547070
1569930 1569930
874478 874478
747988 747988
1215282 1215282
1207000 1207000
1372735 1372735
```